# TabbedBar always visible in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i'm working on an App with Xamarin.forms that have a TabbedPage as main menu
when i go to another page the tab bar disappear , is it possible to make the tab bar always visible ?

Comment: If this is happening you are not doing your navigation correctly.  However, since you have not posted any code its impossible to provide any specific suggestions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.